NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}} when using Azure Openai with Langchain
I am facing an issue resource not found error.
This is what I have tried:

Checked the version, azure_openai_api_key, modelname, version and
everything is correct.
The model was deployed yesterday so more than
5 minutes have passed.
I already have an embeddings model in Azure
openAI and embeddings are created and stored in local.

I have cross checked the logs in Azure and the console says that the requests are reached.
I am not sure why I am getting this error even though everything seems to be correct and in line with Langchain and Azure OpenAI documentation.
import os
import dill  # Import dill instead of pickle
import streamlit as st
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

load_dotenv()

//ex: entries in .env
AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT="https://jkazureopenaiservice.openai.azure.com/"
AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY = "key"
DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "gpt-4o"  # The name of your model deployment in Azure
AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION = "2024-05-13"
AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT = "gpt-4o"


# Azure OpenAI configuration
AZURE_OPENAI_API_BASE = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_BASE")
AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY")
AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION = "2024-05-13"
DEPLOYMENT_NAME = os.getenv("DEPLOYMENT_NAME")


# Path to the folder containing your PDFs
pdf_folder_path = './localKnowledgeHub'

# Initialize a list to hold all documents
all_documents = []

# Load each PDF file
for filename in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        file_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, filename)
        loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path)
        documents = loader.load()
        all_documents.extend(documents)

# Initialize the embeddings model
embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
    model="text-embedding-3-large"
)

# Create the FAISS vector store
#vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(all_documents, embeddings)
#vector_store.save_local("vectorstore")

# Load the vector store locally
vector_store = FAISS.load_local("vectorstore", embeddings, allow_dangerous_deserialization=True)

# Initialize the Azure OpenAI language model
llm = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key=AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    api_version=AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION,
    deployment_name=DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
    temperature=70
)

# Define the prompt template
PROMPT_TEMPLATE = """You are an AI Assistant. Given the following context:
{context}
Answer the following question:
{question}
Assistant:"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=PROMPT_TEMPLATE, input_variables=["context", "question"]
)
# Create a retrieval QA chain using LangChain with the custom prompt
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",  # 'stuff' means directly use documents retrieved
    retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(),
    chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": PROMPT}
)

# Set up the Streamlit UI
st.title("Chatbot")
st.write("Ask me anything a.")

# Input box for user questions
user_question = st.text_input("Question:")

# When the user submits a question
if user_question:    
    # Get the answer from the QA chain using the invoke method
    try:
        result = qa_chain.invoke({"query": user_question})
        answer = result['output_text']
    except Exception as e:
        answer = f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
    
    # Display the answer
    st.write("Answer:", answer)



Instead of AzureOpenAI, try using AzureChatOpenAI.
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI

llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    azure_deployment="name_of_your_deployment",  
    api_version="2024-05-01-preview", 
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=None,
    # other params...
)

Details here: https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/integrations/chat/azure_chat_openai/

AzureOpenAI works with 2024-05-01-preview. what is your point?

@JayashankarGS The API version doesn't matter. AzureOpenAI() only works with gpt-35, as mentioned in the documentation: https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/integrations/llms/azure_openai/

Ok...does api version 2024-05-13 works with AzureChatOpenAI? Since you said it doesn't matter.

Also I have tested from my end it is working perfectly with gpt-4o which is using by user. From workspace chat playground itself I got code for this model.

Didn't try that api version hand's on with LangChain. Tried 2023-08-01 and 2024-05-01, both worked. OP is trying to use with LangChain, its function's have different parameter names than ChatPlayground code.

Do repro on OP data. Also whatever you tried still works with AzureOpenAI function on gpt-4o model.  Recheck it once again.

According to this document the latest preview and GA versions are 2024-07-01-preview and 2024-06-01.
And whatever you given the api version is not supported, so you are getting no resource found error.
Try any one of the above api version.
I tried you code with sample pdf file give one of the above api version.
Output:

You can also find sample code in your ai studio chat playground, where you will the api version supported.

and the code.

It is also recommended to use azure_ad_token_provider instead of using api key.
