Unable to use openai api key and endpoint using python - - openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404
I am trying to connect open ai api and endpoint of Azure Ai Studio with pyhton my code is this:
#code1:
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint = "https://demo1.openai.azure.com/",
  api_key="demo13456543345676543",  
  api_version="2024-05-13"
)

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="mydeployment", # model = "deployment_name".
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Does Azure OpenAI support customer managed keys?"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "Yes, customer managed keys are supported by Azure OpenAI."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Do other Azure AI services support this too?"}
    ]
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)

error:
*openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}
*
code 2:
import streamlit as st
import openai
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.base_url = "https://demo.openai.azure.com/"
openai.api_version = "2024-05-13"  # or any other supported version
openai.api_key = "demo13456789"



st.title("Azure OpenAI Chat Streamlit App")
prompt = st.text_input("Enter your message:")

if st.button("Send Message"):
    if prompt:
        # Call the Azure OpenAI Chat API
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="gpt-35-turbo", 
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}, 
                {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
            ],
            max_tokens=100
        )
        st.write(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
    else:
        st.write("Please enter a message!")

error:
InvalidRequestError: Resource not found
I tried to refer to the documentation, but it is showing the same code works

refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78950258/notfounderror-error-code-404-error-code-404-message-resource/78953015#78953015

hi @saketh-pulijala!
Did you manage to solve the issue?
In what way?
I'm facing the same problem

I guess I did not.

the code is 100% working, i just tested it out with my endpoint see below
the 3 things could lead to 404 error are below. make sure you find them explicitly in azure's endpoint page. (see last screenshot)

azure_endpoint
api_version
model (deployment name)



